# Finding the average kinetic energy of the molecules using thermodynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, molecules

I've a simple problem:

In a balloon with volume $V=0.05m^3$, there is $0.12 kmol$ gas $\frac{m}{\mu}=0.12kmol$, under pressure $P=0.6*10^7Pa$.

Find the average kinetic energy of the molecules?

The  first thing that came in my mind was the formula:

$PV=\frac{2}{3}*N_a*<E_{ki}>$, where $N_a$ is Avogadro constant and $<E_{ki}>$ is the avarage kinetic energy, however when I took a look at the solution, I saw it presented this way:

From

$PV=\frac{2}{3}E_k=\frac{2}{3}N*E_{ki}$ and
$\frac{m}{\mu}=\frac{N}{N_a} $

$=>$ $PV = \frac{2m}{3 \mu}N_a<E_ki>; <E_ki> = \frac{3\mu PV}{2mN_a}$

I've checked the formula in my textbook, and it's written  the way I thought.

Is the solution provided in my textbook wrong, or have I missed some concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is for one mole of gas and the textbook equation is for $n =\frac {N}{N_a}=\frac{m}{\mu}$ moles of gas.  Note that $\frac {N}{N_a}$ and $\frac{m}{\mu}$ have no units, they are dimensionless.